# Github Push fatal: repository not found (hyphenated username)

Tags: github, mingw

Trying to get started with GitHub for the first time.  I was following the instructions on the GitHub website to just set up a simple repository and push the Readme file to it.
I wanted to use the terminal first before using  a GUI like Github for Windows.  So I'm using MINGW32 as the site suggested. However whenever I go to push my file I get

```
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/fidflash/Hello-World.git/' not found
```

I'm sure it's because my username is kid-flash not kidflash.  It seems that the terminal is trimming the hyphen out of my username in the URL.  I use the hyphen when I type in my username.  It even prompts `"Password for 'https://kid-flash@github.com': "`

any ideas how to keep the terminal (or maybe it's Git doing it) from trimming my username?
thanks

Comment: what is fidflash vs. kidflash here?

Answer (score 0):

Got a response from GitHub support tonight:

> I think the dash is actually missing from the origin remote's URL. Can
>   you try setting the origin remote with the following command and
>   pushing again?
>
> $ git remote set-url origin
>   https://github.com/kid-flash/Hello-World.git

I tried it and it worked perfectly.